# Unable to run Testng tests by Invoking browser specific node using selenium grid2

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Am facing a problem when running my test cases which are written in java (testng) using selenium grid2.
This are the steps which i followed

1. invoked the hub using "java -jar selenium-server-standalone.2.20.0.jar -role hub"
2. Invoked a node with browser specific  (java -jar selenium-server-standalone.2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:444/gird/register" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=11.0,maxInstance=5")
3. trying to run tests from command prompt.

am getting error when i am following this steps.

if i am invoking the node without browser specific am not getting any error.

Can some help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks
Raghuram

Answer (score 0):

There are incorrect hub port (444 instead of 4444) and odd `"` symbol before -browser. Please, copy and paste the following code to cmd:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/gird/register -browser "browserName=firefox,version=11.0,maxInstance=5"
```